# non breaking space after a one-letter words

Tags: jquery, mysql, css, text, typography

In my native language, Polish,a properly formated text cannot have a single letter words at the end of the line. 
In blog entries and short pieces of writing I just put

```
&nbsp;
```

after such words and the job is done.

Is there any way of handling the issue in CSS or jQuery?

I consider fixing a collection of 30 000 quotations with the solution I get here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In CSS, I don't think so. Try specifying the right language in a `Content-Language` header, or the `lang` attribute of the `<html>` tag. With a bit of luck some browsers know how to handle those situations, if it is indeed a rule in your language (which language by the way?). If this doesn't work, you will probably need to solve it server side of in JavaScript. I would prefer a server side solution then.

Comment: i have found this discussion http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27780/one-letter-word-at-the-end-of-line but it seems nobody cares about thhe issue. Even puristic  sites on Polish language seem not to approach this issue. just as an anecdote, failing to write months names in genitive case is common even on Polish govt pages.

Comment: If setting the language doesn't work, you would have to add those `&nbsp;`s yourself. Regular Expressions seem the obvious choice, but for HTML they are bad news (you don't want to change `<a href` to `<a&nbsp;href`). A simple parser for this purpose should be doable... Then again, if purist sites and professional typesetting tools don't take this into account, maybe it's not worth it. Although I've put quite some effort in properly displaying an [IJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJ_%28digraph%29) in a wiki, so I know what it feels like to be purist. ;)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I added a small script in jQuery to my page. This is probably not too clean code but it works. If anyone has an idea how to improve it, can paste in here for others.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var myArray = ["a", "A", "i", "I", "o", "O", "u", "U", "w", "W", "z", "Z", "e", "E", "aż", "Aż", "bo", "Bo", "by", "By", "iż", "Iż", "ni", "Ni", "że", "Że", "do", "Do", "ku", "Ku", "na", "Na", "od", "Od", "po", "Po", "we", "We", "za", "Za", "ze", "Ze", "hę", "Hę", "no", "No", "ot", "Ot", "aa", "Aa", "aj", "Aj", "am", "Am", "au", "Au", "ba", "Ba", "ee", "Ee", "eh", "Eh", "ej", "Ej", "fe", "Fe", "fi", "Fi", "fi", "Fi", "fu", "Fu", "ha", "Ha", "he", "He", "ho", "Ho", "ii", "Ii", "oj", "Oj", "oo", "Oo", "ot", "Ot", "oż", "Oż", "pa", "Pa", "uf", "Uf", "uu", "Uu", "co", "Co", "ki", "Ki", "se", "Se", "ja", "Ja", "ty", "Ty", "ci", "Ci", "on", "On", "mu", "Mu", "go", "Go", "oń", "Oń", "ją", "Ją", "my", "My", "wy", "Wy", "im", "Im", "je", "Je", "ma", "Ma", "mą", "Mą", "me", "Me", "ów", "Ów", "ta", "Ta", "tę", "Tę", "tą", "Tą", "to", "To", "te", "Te", "tu", "Tu", "al", "Al", "ar", "Ar", "as", "Aa", "at", "At", "bi", "Bi", "er", "Er", "es", "Es", "ew", "Ew", "ez", "Ez", "go", "Go", "id", "Id", "ił", "Ił", "iw", "Iw", "li", "Li", "ok", "Ok", "om", "Om", "op", "Op", "or", "Or", "os", "Os", "oś", "Oś", "oz", "Oz", "ód", "Ód", "ós", "Ós", "su", "Su", "ud", "Ud", "ul", "Ul", "ut", "Ut", "je", "Je", "ma", "Ma", "są", "Są", "lub", "Lub", "ale", "Ale", "czy", "Czy", "nad", "Nad", "pod", "Pod", "bez", "Bez", "nie", "Nie", "tak", "Tak", "albo", "Albo", "więc", "Więc", "lecz", "Lecz", "przez", "Przez", "niech", "Niech", "tylko", "Tylko"];

    for (var i=0,  total = myArray.length; i < total; i++) {

        var myArrayItem = (myArray[i]); 

            jQuery('p').each(function() {

                var text = jQuery(this).html();
                jQuery(this).html(text.replace(new RegExp(' '+myArrayItem+' ', 'g') , ' '+myArrayItem+'&nbsp;'));

            });

    }

});
```